# PyMC beginner: how to actually sample from the fitted model

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, pymc

I'm trying a very simple model: fitting a Normal where I assume I know the precision, and I just want to find the mean. The code below seems to fit the Normal correctly. But after fitting, I want to sample from the model, ie generate new data which is similar to my `data` variable. I know I can use `trace("mean")` to get samples for the mean variable. But how can I get new samples from the model itself?

I've looked at docs eg http://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc/database.html#accessing-sampled-data. I've also looked at quite a few examples, eg the mining disasters, and several from the Probabilistic Programming notebooks, and none mention this. I (more or less an MCMC beginner) expected that sampling from the fitted model was the whole point! What am I missing?

```
from pymc import *
data = np.array([-1, 0, 4, 0, 2, -2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, -3, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1])
mean = Uniform("mean", -4, 4)
precision = 2.0**-2
obs = Normal("obs", mean, precision, value=data, observed=True)
model = Model( {"mean": mean, "obs": obs})
mcmc = MCMC(model)
mcmc.sample(10000, 1000, 1)
# I can get samples for the "mean" variable
mean_samples = mcmc.trace("mean")[:]
hist(mean_samples)
# but how can I do the equivalent of mcmc.trace("obs")?
```

Comment: Exactly the question I had! Wondering if the predictive sampling is simplified in pymc3...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are looking the what's called the *predictive distribution*. To include this is very simple. Before creating the `Model`, add the additional stochastic variable:

```
predictive = mc.Normal( "predictive", mean, precision )
model = Model( {"mean": mean, "obs": obs, "pred":predictive})

...

predictive_traces = mcmc.trace("predictive")[:]
hist( predictive_traces )
```

[image: Artificial data from the fitted model]

This will generate artifical data from the fitted model. Thanks for bringing this oversight to my attention, I'll include it in the BMH project.

Comment: How do you create an array of n random variables in which n is random? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45283843/pymc-what-s-the-best-way-to-create-an-array-with-a-random-number-of-random-var (Sorry is this is too much...)

Answer (score 5):

Landed here several years later when looking for the same thing using PyMC3, so I am going to leave an answer relevant to the new version: (from [Posterior Predictive Checks](https://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/posterior_predictive.html)).

```
ppc = pm.sample_ppc(trace, samples=500, model=model, size=100)
```

> Now, ppc contains 500 generated data sets (containing 100 samples each), each using a different parameter setting from the posterior.

Comment: The newest version of these docs is [Prior and Posterior Predictive Checks](https://www.pymc.io/projects/docs/en/latest/learn/core_notebooks/posterior_predictive.html), and the new version of the function is `pm.sample_posterior_predictive`